# How to check if Excel file is checked out

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to check-out and edit an Excel file. It's possible that by the time the code runs the file was already checked out by the same user on the same computer. In that case `CanCheckOut()` returns false, and the code below is not working.

```
// xlsAsp is an instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

if (!xlsApp.Workbooks.CanCheckOut(fileName))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File {0} cannot be checked out", fileName);
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("Attempting to check out {0}", fileName);
currentBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

xlsApp.Workbooks.CheckOut(fileName);

// Do something 
currentBook.CheckIn(SaveChanges: true);
```

I would like to change the code to handle the situation when the file is checked out.

Is it possible somehow to verify if a file is already checked-out, to avoid checking out for the second time?

Comment: we used WebDAV to achieve this.. I couldn't remember code on top of my head.. Following this question.. I am waiting to see some solid reply.

Comment: You mean checked out *by the same user on the same computer*?

Comment: Um... If the file is already checked out and the code prevents the attempt to check out then, by definition, the code IS working (as designed - or at least as presented).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, yes. I've update the question to include that.